# Code injection thorugh Visual Studio 2015, How to remove code for security

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, code-injection, inline-assembly, dll-injection

I used to develop code injection programs with Visual Studio 2010 (maybe 5 years ago?).

Now I need it again and I developed it pretty much the same as before (with Visual Studio 2015).

However, I have confirmed that the codes I have not seen before are generated.

[image]

The first thing I found is the above problem.

It seems that the program's entry point, the address of the function, uses the table without pointing directly to the contents.

The problem is that I can not find the address and size of the injected code.

Is there a way to disable it?

[image]

The second problem is that weird functions are added.

My injection code is code that calls CreateProcess, ExitProcess.

However, each address is called immediately after each function is called.

This is the part of `0x013A14CE : CALL test.013A1DA0` above.

[image]

The contents of the function are as above.

This problem causes a crash after injecting the code.

I do not know what this is doing, but I think it's code for security.

I found several compile options, but I could not solve the problem.

I tried to compile with Visual Studio 2010, but the result was the same.

Inline assembly seems to be able to solve this problem, but it seems hard to solve it every time there is a fix.

please answer my question

Comment: @RaghuAriga Thanks to your Suggested Edits.

I do not think I can write well because I am not good at English.

Comment: i understand, everyone have to start at some point.